# Error al abrir el Terminal del Mac

Tags: bash, macos

Desde hace un tiempo mi terminal de **MAC** me ofrece un error cada vez que abro una pantalla nueva de mi terminal, he estado buscando información por Google y la verdad es que no he encontrado nada convincente, os muestro el error:

```
-bash: /Users/name/.rvm/script/rvm: No such file or directory

-bash: /Users/name/.bash_profile: line 11: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

-bash: /Users/name/.bash_profile: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Fichero **.bash_profile**:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$

source ~/.rvm/script/rvm

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(rbenv init -)"

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/name/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-buil$

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/name/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-buil$
```

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que pongas el contenido de tu .bash_profile o tu .bashrc, el primer error me parece que está relacionado al Ruby Version Manager

Comment: Gracias @César ya ha sido publicado.

Comment: Hola @RamónDevesa, la solucion que te aportaron te sirvió? Si fue así, por favor marcala como valida. Eso ayuda a mejorar stackoverflow.

Comment: Buenas @abkrimme pues si, me solucionó mis dos últimas líneas de problemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fichero `.bash_profile` tiene un error en esta línea:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Si te fijas se cierran comillas, pero no se abren. Debería ser así:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Arregla eso y comprueba si ahora te funciona. Si no, actualiza la pregunta con el error y podemos continuar a partir de ahí.

Comment: Buenos días Alvaro, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.